# Scrolling is inherited between windows in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome3, scrolling

Rather odd behaviour I've picked up on; after scrolling (a noticeably large amount) in one window, alt-tabbing to another window and then attempting to scroll even just a single line, this new window scrolls by both that single line *and* the previous window's scrolling action.

If done with a large initial scroll, this is very obvious as it'll cause the second page to scroll well beyond a single scroll "tick" as expected with a mouse with a discrete scroll-wheel.

[Here's a video of me attempting to demonstrate this.](https://streamable.com/kblna)

To replicate yourself:

1. Open two windows with content long enough to allow noticeable scrolling.
2. Focus one, then alt-tab to the other so that you can easily switch directly between the two with a single "alt-tab".
3. Scroll from the top of one down a sizeable length
4. Switch to the second and attempt to scroll only a single "tick"

I've had this happen on my personal laptop, a desktop that I use and also confirmed it occurring for a friend on their desktop.

Does this occur for anyone else, and does anyone know if this is intentional?

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, we prefer that every question on [SE] should actually contain a question.

Comment: I agree, what I was asking wasn't too clear. Edited to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply but this seems to be a bug in WebKit:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807187
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608246

Comment: Definitely this. 

Can be observed in Electron-based applications as well, see: [atom#15482](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15482) and
[vscode#28795](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28795)

Answer (score 0):

Besides Srdjan's and Frohman's pointed issues (which are still open in 2022), this bug is also pointed in

- GitHub: [pop-os/pop#2331](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2331)
- GitLab: [GNOME/mutter#401](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/401)

I created a GNOME Shell Extension as a temporary fix to this problem:

- Name: Alt+Tab Scroll Workaround
- Link: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5282/alttab-scroll-workaround/
- Code: https://github.com/lucasresck/gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-scroll-workaround

It's not definitive, but it can ease the difficulty of, e.g., using Chrome and VS Code at the same time.